# Java program runnin in Eclipse causes EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, eclipse, fatal-error, ntdll

I'm experiencing a problem with a Java application running in Eclipse.
At arbitrary times during execution, the application crashes with the following error and dump.

Some further information that may help:

- the errors first started occurring after I had a problem with the project settings (wrong path to JVM that had to be corrected)
- errors still occur after an update to the latest Java version
- the application uses JNA to load and use LibNoDave
- it is not always the same thread (here it's `ManagerRBG3`) that causes the crash; the interesting thing, however, is that - assuming it's a problem with JNA - the threads causing crashes are never the ones that use the `libnodave.dll` directly, but rather through a seperate thread handling all communication through the use of LibNoDave

I tried searching SO, but the only results that came up had to do with the `jvm.dll` being the problematic frame. Here it's the `ntdll.dll`.

Any hits or ideas on what may be causing this? Or am I looking at this from a completely wrong standpoint?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x774fe3be, pid=4340, tid=2328
#
# JRE version: 7.0_13-b20
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]  RtlInitUnicodeString+0x196
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0580cc00):  JavaThread "ManagerRBG3" [_thread_blocked, id=2328, stack(0x09160000,0x091b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x4f029ddd

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x05a9cc78, ECX=0x002d0000, EDX=0x05a9cc78
ESP=0x091af140, EBP=0x091af174, ESI=0x4f029dd9, EDI=0x05a9cc70
EIP=0x774fe3be, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x091af140)
0x091af140:   00000000 002d0000 05a9cc78 091af0f8
0x091af150:   091af16c 00000000 00000064 00000000
0x091af160:   056de610 05a9cc78 00000000 000005b8
0x091af170:   05a9cc70 091af18c 774fe023 056de610
0x091af180:   05a9cc78 fffffffd 05a9cc70 091af1a0
0x091af190:   753514dd 002d0000 00000000 05a9cc78
0x091af1a0:   091af1b4 71a6016a 002d0000 00000000
0x091af1b0:   05a9cc78 091af1dc 6dfdea6c 05a9cc78 

Instructions: (pc=0x774fe3be)
0x774fe39e:   7a f8 80 7f 07 05 0f 84 5b 4b 06 00 8b 07 8b f7
0x774fe3ae:   c1 ee 03 33 f0 33 35 a4 00 5d 77 89 7d fc 33 f1
0x774fe3be:   8b 46 04 89 45 f4 c6 47 07 80 c6 47 06 00 8b 5e
0x774fe3ce:   08 8b 4e 0c 89 5d e0 83 c3 01 89 4d e4 83 d1 01 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x05a9cc78 is an unknown value
ECX=0x002d0000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x05a9cc78 is an unknown value
ESP=0x091af140 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0580cc00
EBP=0x091af174 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0580cc00
ESI=0x4f029dd9 is an unknown value
EDI=0x05a9cc70 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x09160000,0x091b0000],  sp=0x091af140,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e3be]  RtlInitUnicodeString+0x196
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e023]  RtlFreeHeap+0x7e
C  [kernel32.dll+0x114dd]  HeapFree+0x14
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x1016a]  free+0x1c
V  [jvm.dll+0x17ea6c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd37d1]
J  java.lang.Thread.sleep(J)V
J  ch.dev.mfr.main.ManagerRBG.run()V
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a34a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d968e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a533]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a597]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd306f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14a647]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14a7b0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17ee89]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c6de]  endthreadex+0x3a
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c788]  endthreadex+0xe4
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133aa]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ef2]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ec5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.lang.Thread.sleep(J)V
J  ch.dev.mfr.main.ManagerRBG.run()V
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x057f0400 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.82_FA.83" [_thread_blocked, id=844, stack(0x0a6c0000,0x0a710000)]
  0x057e6800 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.88_FA.89" [_thread_blocked, id=4736, stack(0x0a0f0000,0x0a140000)]
  0x057e5400 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.1_FA.2" [_thread_blocked, id=4432, stack(0x0a620000,0x0a670000)]
  0x057e5000 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.3_FA.4" [_thread_blocked, id=4316, stack(0x0a5c0000,0x0a610000)]
  0x057e5c00 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.33_FA.34" [_thread_blocked, id=4604, stack(0x09760000,0x097b0000)]
  0x057e6000 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.29_FA.30" [_thread_blocked, id=4696, stack(0x08df0000,0x08e40000)]
  0x0a056c00 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.45_HR.4_1" [_thread_blocked, id=1140, stack(0x096e0000,0x09730000)]
  0x0584a400 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.89_HR.5_1" [_thread_blocked, id=4156, stack(0x0a3d0000,0x0a420000)]
  0x0a053c00 JavaThread "Bwg_HR.1_FA.102_1" [_thread_blocked, id=4864, stack(0x0a280000,0x0a2d0000)]
  0x05863c00 JavaThread "Bwg_FA.101_HR.1_1" [_thread_blocked, id=3440, stack(0x09630000,0x09680000)]
  0x05810000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=4332, stack(0x00ce0000,0x00d30000)]
  0x0580f800 JavaThread "Profil_Lampen_Fred" [_thread_blocked, id=4892, stack(0x07320000,0x07370000)]
  0x0580f400 JavaThread "MfrHeartbeat" [_thread_blocked, id=1020, stack(0x055b0000,0x05600000)]
  0x0580ec00 JavaThread "CheckSqlConnection" [_thread_blocked, id=5020, stack(0x09500000,0x09550000)]
  0x0580e800 JavaThread "MFR" [_thread_blocked, id=3744, stack(0x09560000,0x095b0000)]
  0x0580e000 JavaThread "Coss" [_thread_blocked, id=2016, stack(0x09460000,0x094b0000)]
  0x0580d800 JavaThread "OPCServer" [_thread_in_native, id=2028, stack(0x09320000,0x09370000)]
=>0x0580cc00 JavaThread "ManagerRBG3" [_thread_blocked, id=2328, stack(0x09160000,0x091b0000)]
  0x0580c800 JavaThread "ManagerRBG2" [_thread_blocked, id=2032, stack(0x052e0000,0x05330000)]
  0x05773800 JavaThread "ManagerRBG1" [_thread_blocked, id=316, stack(0x08f50000,0x08fa0000)]
  0x05703400 JavaThread "ManagerAZ" [_thread_blocked, id=4296, stack(0x08fd0000,0x09020000)]
  0x05702c00 JavaThread "ManagerVW" [_thread_blocked, id=4344, stack(0x08e60000,0x08eb0000)]
  0x0570c400 JavaThread "ConfigUpdater" [_thread_blocked, id=1872, stack(0x08d00000,0x08d50000)]
  0x05724000 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2320, stack(0x08ca0000,0x08cf0000)]
  0x05729000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=3296, stack(0x07ea0000,0x07ef0000)]
  0x0577ac00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3380, stack(0x05600000,0x05650000)]
  0x0571d000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=772, stack(0x05ac0000,0x05b10000)]
  0x056b1000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2024, stack(0x05560000,0x055b0000)]
  0x04ac6400 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3896, stack(0x04ff0000,0x05040000)]
  0x004df400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3680, stack(0x04840000,0x04890000)]
  0x004c8000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4580, stack(0x01240000,0x01290000)]
  0x004c6c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4588, stack(0x01290000,0x012e0000)]
  0x004c3c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4084, stack(0x04760000,0x047b0000)]
  0x004ae000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4568, stack(0x01110000,0x01160000)]
  0x004ac800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5068, stack(0x01160000,0x011b0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x004ab000 VMThread [stack: 0x01090000,0x010e0000] [id=4328]
  0x0491b400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04cb0000,0x04d00000] [id=5060]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 40619K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,  28% used [0x14420000, 0x16ba1c28, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9288, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4415K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30fcd8, 0x1f30fe00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x34997708, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00db0000,0x00ee0000] byte_map_base: 0x00d0df00

Polling page: 0x00190000

Code Cache  [0x02750000, 0x02e68000, 0x04750000)
 total_blobs=2591 nmethods=2350 adapters=174 free_code_cache=25512Kb largest_free_block=26123840

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 36900.921 Thread 0x004c8000 2348   !         sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$2::run (637 bytes)
Event: 36900.925 Thread 0x004c8000 nmethod 2348 0x02e5f8c8 code [0x02e5fd50, 0x02e614a4]
Event: 37807.245 Thread 0x004c8000 2349   !         com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl::isClosed (41 bytes)
Event: 37807.246 Thread 0x004c8000 nmethod 2349 0x02e64648 code [0x02e64780, 0x02e64a64]
Event: 37817.334 Thread 0x004c8000 2350             sun.util.PreHashedMap::get (73 bytes)
Event: 37817.334 Thread 0x004c8000 nmethod 2350 0x02e64c88 code [0x02e64dc0, 0x02e64fb8]
Event: 37838.539 Thread 0x004c8000 2351   !         sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil::textToNumericFormatV4 (402 bytes)
Event: 37838.540 Thread 0x004c8000 nmethod 2351 0x02e651c8 code [0x02e65350, 0x02e65a14]
Event: 37855.451 Thread 0x004c8000 2352             java.lang.ClassLoader::getCallerClassLoader (16 bytes)
Event: 37855.451 Thread 0x004c8000 nmethod 2352 0x02e65f48 code [0x02e66050, 0x02e66108]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 39989.637 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7930 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 139921K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K, 100% used [0x14420000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1ccc4548, 0x1ddb0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddb0000, 0x1eec0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4413K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f410, 0x1f30f600, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
Event: 39989.640 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7931 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 166K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,   0% used [0x14420000, 0x14420000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9938, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4413K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f410, 0x1f30f600, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
}
Event: 39993.603 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7931 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 139942K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K, 100% used [0x14420000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9938, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4413K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f410, 0x1f30f600, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
Event: 39993.606 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7932 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 165K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,   0% used [0x14420000, 0x14420000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1ccc9658, 0x1ddb0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddb0000, 0x1eec0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4413K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f4a8, 0x1f30f600, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
}
Event: 39997.737 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7932 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 139941K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K, 100% used [0x14420000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1ccc9658, 0x1ddb0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddb0000, 0x1eec0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4413K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f4a8, 0x1f30f600, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
Event: 39997.740 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7933 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 165K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,   0% used [0x14420000, 0x14420000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9490, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4414K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f9d0, 0x1f30fa00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
}
Event: 40001.760 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7933 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 139941K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K, 100% used [0x14420000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9490, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4414K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f9d0, 0x1f30fa00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
Event: 40001.764 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7934 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 166K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,   0% used [0x14420000, 0x14420000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1ccc9be0, 0x1ddb0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddb0000, 0x1eec0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4414K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f9d0, 0x1f30fa00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x349976d8, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
}
Event: 40005.714 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7934 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 139942K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K, 100% used [0x14420000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1ccc9be0, 0x1ddb0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddb0000, 0x1eec0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4414K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30f9d0, 0x1f30fa00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x34997708, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
Event: 40005.717 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=7935 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 164K [0x14420000, 0x1eec0000, 0x1eec0000)
  eden space 139776K,   0% used [0x14420000, 0x14420000, 0x1cca0000)
  from space 17472K,   0% used [0x1ddb0000, 0x1ddd9288, 0x1eec0000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x1cca0000, 0x1cca0000, 0x1ddb0000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 4415K [0x1eec0000, 0x34420000, 0x34420000)
   the space 349568K,   1% used [0x1eec0000, 0x1f30fcd8, 0x1f30fe00, 0x34420000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 5597K [0x34420000, 0x35020000, 0x38420000)
   the space 12288K,  45% used [0x34420000, 0x34997708, 0x34997800, 0x35020000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38420000, 0x38861958, 0x38861a00, 0x38e20000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x38e20000, 0x394a25f0, 0x394a2600, 0x39a20000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 38802.223 Thread 0x0580e800 Implicit null exception at 0x029a57b1 to 0x029a611a
Event: 38802.223 Thread 0x0580e800 Threw 0x1ae08a48 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u13_2932_new\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:613
Event: 39053.803 Thread 0x05702c00 Implicit null exception at 0x029a57b1 to 0x029a611a
Event: 39053.803 Thread 0x05702c00 Threw 0x1673af40 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u13_2932_new\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:613
Event: 39326.152 Thread 0x0580e800 Implicit null exception at 0x029a57b1 to 0x029a611a
Event: 39326.152 Thread 0x0580e800 Threw 0x1ad25b50 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u13_2932_new\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:613
Event: 39806.367 Thread 0x0580e800 Implicit null exception at 0x029a57b1 to 0x029a611a
Event: 39806.367 Thread 0x0580e800 Threw 0x189ebd20 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u13_2932_new\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:613
Event: 39950.262 Thread 0x0580e800 Implicit null exception at 0x029a57b1 to 0x029a611a
Event: 39950.262 Thread 0x0580e800 Threw 0x17f3c698 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u13_2932_new\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:613

Events (10 events):
Event: 40006.838 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread added: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.840 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread exited: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.841 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread added: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.843 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread exited: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.844 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread added: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.845 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread exited: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.846 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread added: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.847 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread exited: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.848 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread added: 0x057f0800
Event: 40006.850 Thread 0x057f0800 Thread exited: 0x057f0800


Dynamic libraries:
0x01320000 - 0x0134f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x774d0000 - 0x77650000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x75340000 - 0x75450000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75130000 - 0x75177000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x754e0000 - 0x75580000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74c10000 - 0x74cbc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75ad0000 - 0x75ae9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x74ee0000 - 0x74fd0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74bb0000 - 0x74c10000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74bac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x769f0000 - 0x76af0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x76960000 - 0x769f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x75910000 - 0x7591a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x74cc0000 - 0x74d5d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x713b0000 - 0x7154e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x75cb0000 - 0x75d07000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74d60000 - 0x74dc0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75580000 - 0x7564c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71b0e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x6de60000 - 0x6e1ad000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71a40000 - 0x71a47000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75650000 - 0x75685000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x774a0000 - 0x774a6000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x712d0000 - 0x71302000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75840000 - 0x75845000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x71a30000 - 0x71a3c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x71a10000 - 0x71a30000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x719f0000 - 0x71a03000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x71550000 - 0x71564000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x74a60000 - 0x74a9c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x74870000 - 0x74876000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x713a0000 - 0x713ae000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x70ce0000 - 0x70e22000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x75180000 - 0x7520f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x74fd0000 - 0x7512c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x748c0000 - 0x748d6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74880000 - 0x748bb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x71380000 - 0x71397000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x73b30000 - 0x73b3b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x73a00000 - 0x73a10000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x739f0000 - 0x73a00000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x739d0000 - 0x739e2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x73c80000 - 0x73cc4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x739c0000 - 0x739c8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x74860000 - 0x74865000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73d40000 - 0x73d5c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73d30000 - 0x73d37000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x71370000 - 0x71376000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x71330000 - 0x71368000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1003d000     C:\Users\visu\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-Visu\jna2805342089407974779.dll
0x002e0000 - 0x00301000     C:\Users\visu\workspace\IDMFRv2\lib\libnodave-0.8.4.6\win\libnodave.dll
0x71c60000 - 0x71c73000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x6fc20000 - 0x6fde3000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x744e0000 - 0x744e9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x71310000 - 0x71316000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x6fec0000 - 0x6ffb6000     C:\Windows\system32\dlumd32.dll
0x756a0000 - 0x7583d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x758e0000 - 0x75907000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75320000 - 0x75332000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x73a20000 - 0x73b0b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
0x71d30000 - 0x71d3d000     C:\Windows\system32\wtsapi32.dll
0x6a2b0000 - 0x6b11e000     C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dum.dll
0x711c0000 - 0x711e5000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
0x75d10000 - 0x7695a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x712a0000 - 0x712ca000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x75210000 - 0x75293000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x70ca0000 - 0x70cd1000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\t2k.dll
0x71280000 - 0x712a0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\sunec.dll
0x71320000 - 0x71329000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x74dc0000 - 0x74ede000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x75690000 - 0x7569c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: ch.dev.mfr.main.Main --gui
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\
USERNAME=Visu
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 30 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 16768056k(14112604k free), swap 33534260k(30370904k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_13-b20), built on Jan 30 2013 10:03:58 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Jul 23 08:44:19 2013
elapsed time: 40006 seconds
```

**Edit**: I'm using JNA, not JNI. Sorry for the mixup.

**Edit2**: clarification on the use of LibNoDave

**Update**:

I am now running the unmodified software on a freshly installed linux machine. So far no complications have occurred. This leads me to assume that the problem may lie with the Java installation on the machine running eclipse.

Is it possible that there may have been complications during one or any Java updates that could have led to JNA misbehaving?

I am not all that familiar with the Java update process, but from what I've read recently, it's not at all uncommon for Java to - for lack of a better term - "break itself".

Comment: It's probably not a libdonave.dll issue. I'm getting the same error using only Junit 4 and POJOs.

Comment: I had this problem after I installed a bunch of updates to 4.23.0. Installing the latest release of Eclipse did not solve the problem. I installed 4.24.0 and the problem went away. I have no idea why. Note that I got a Java error code of -1073740771 (0xc000005).

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume that just because the crash is not happening within `libnodave.dll` it isn't that library's fault. That library's code may be bringing about an inconsistency either within the JVM or the underlying OS services, which is later causing another system call to fail. This is especially indicated by the fact that the errors happen at different place each time.

Try to replace calls to `libnodave.dll` with mocked Java code and see if you receive the error again.

Comment: I may not have been all too clear in expressing myself. What I meant was, that the threads causing the crase do not use the dll *directly* - but indirectly by passing their information to other classes. However, I'm not assuming that libnodave is flawless. I just can't explain the fact that it used to work without problems until about a week ago. And I haven't changed the dll.